# What to choose to use to determine the relationship?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I have 3 tables:

1. table city (500 000 records)
2. table post (A city can have many posts)
3. table post_text (To store the text of the post)

table city has fields ID, NAME
table post has fields ID, CITY_ID, POST_ID
table post_text has fields TITLE, TEXT

What to use?
Polymorphic? Through? Something else?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Why do you create a different table to text and title of post?

Comment: Create the right connection

Comment: Due to the large amount of data, To quickly find all the posts of the city